# Caffe: concatenation layer in python (L.Concat)

Tags: python, neural-network, concatenation, convolution, caffe

I wonder how to perform a concatenation of two layers into one in python. More specifically, I want to join the output of a pooling (subsampling) layer with not-visual data to then put a fully connected layer on top of that.

Let's say the subsampling layer will output neurons with shape 64*2*2 (if we ignore the caffe batch_size) and that the data layer I want to join on contains only 1 feature (a speed float that ranges from 0 to 1).

Here is some dummy code to put you in context:

```
import numpy as np

import caffe
from caffe import layers as L
from caffe import params as P

# ...

n.conv4 = L.Convolution(n.relu3, kernel_size=3, num_output=64, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
n.pool4 = L.Pooling(n.conv4, kernel_size=3, stride=2, pool=P.Pooling.AVE)
# Data of shape `batch_size*64*2*2` out of this layer (if dropout ignored). 
n.relu4 = L.ReLU(n.pool4, in_place=True)

###
# This is what I want to know how to do, yet this might not even be
# the good way to call the function:
n.join_speed = L.Concat([n.relu4, n.data_speed], in_place=True)
####

n.ip1 = L.InnerProduct(n.join_speed, num_output=512, weight_filler=dict(type='xavier'))
n.sig1 = L.Sigmoid(n.ip1, in_place=True)

# ...
```

Comment: you might need to add a `"Reshpe"` layer to flatten the `n.relu4` output.

Comment: In a similar neural network I have made, my `n.relu4` was directly fed into the `n.ip1` without any reshape nor concat. Would this be wrong, but working?

Comment: if you feed *only* `n.relu4` to `n.ip1` caffe will "flatten" it for you. but if you concat two blobs, you must make sure their dimensions are compatible first.

Comment: @Shai: Do you know how can we make concate layer input in prototxt as the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778274/how-to-generate-concate-layer-prototxt-using-python? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have figured out the answer to your question, but if you haven't then you may want to try the following:

```
bottom_layers = [n.relu4, n.data_speed]
n.join_speed = L.Concat(*bottom_layers)
```

The above should allow you to call Concat layer via pycaffe/python layer.

Answer (score 0):

I am similarly trying to do a python-generated deconv layer

```
n.deconv8 = L.Deconvolution(n.conv7)
```

works ok but

```
n.deconv8 = L.Deconvolution(n.conv7,kernel_size=2)
```

hits

```
AttributeError: 'LayerParameter' object has no attribute 'kernel_size'
```

and similarly for

```
n.deconv8 = L.Deconvolution(n.conv7,num_output=1024)
```

so is there some new syntax for indicating these parameters (also weight_filler, bias_filler,stride)

Comment: btw the bottom_layers = [n.relu4, n.data_speed]
n.join_speed = L.Concat(*bottom_layers)
 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

L.Concat(top1, top2, top3) works for me